# Stream-based regular expression matching library for python2 or python3

Tags: open-source, python, streaming, regex

Due to requirements of python's `re` module to allow going back into the input it consequently doesn't provide a possibility to pass anything else than a string as an argument to central functions of `re` (anything else wouldn't make a lot of sense if any). It is theoretically possible to implement regular expression matching based on streams if the backwards navigation isn't required and my question is now whether that has happened already and the results made available as FLOSS library. The only application I'm interested in is returning the positions of a found match.

I found `regex` 2014.10.24 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) and `re2` 0.2.20 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/re2/) don't seem to support such features according to their project descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/nitely/regexy

> A Python library for parsing, compiling, and executing regular
>   expressions. All searches execute in linear time with respect to the
>   size of the regular expression and search text.
>
> Streams are supported (i.e: network and files)